# Convergence of a series with alternating denominator - Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Decide if the series converges absolutely, conditionally, or not at all.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2+(-1)^n)n}
\end{equation}

I'm having a lot of trouble with this one. I know the even terms will be of the form $\frac{1}{3n}$ and the odd terms of the form $-\frac{1}{n}$ but I'm not really sure how I can use that to prove convergence. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiply by $-1$ in order to make things nicer, and let the resulting series be $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$. Then the sum of the $(2n-1)$-th term and the $(2n)$-th term is $\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{6n}$.  Simplify.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think he meant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2+(-1)^n)n}$.

Comment: I multiplied by $-1$ because of a dislike of negative numbers. Makes no difference to convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2+(-1)^n)n}=\frac{H_N}{6}-\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{H_N}{6}-H_{2N+1}+\frac{H_N}{2}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2+(-1)^n)n}=\frac{1}{3}\log N-\log(2N)+O(1)=-\frac{2}{3}\log N+O(1)$$
so the series diverges towards $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Andre Nicolas's hint above:

$-S_{2n}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{3(2k)}\right)$  where $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{3(2k)}>\frac{1}{3k}$, so

$-S_{2n}>\frac{1}{3}H_{n}\implies S_{2n}<-\frac{1}{3}H_{n}\implies\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=-\infty$ and hence the series diverges.

Answer (score -3):

I agree with your analysis of the problem:
even terms will be of the form 1/3n and the odd terms of the form −1/n.  Then each of them will converge to the same number 0.  so the whole thing will converge to 0.  Afterward, you can prove by induction.

Comment: The question is asking for the sum, not the limit, of the sequence.